# Make the UNIQUE() function to evaluate only the first column of a table when searching for duplicates instead of entire rows

Tags: excel, duplicates, unique

I want the dynamic array function UNIQUE() to return a table with unique values based on another table where only the first column (Article) is evaluated when searching for duplicates.

As of now, UNIQUE() always evaluates entire rows of the array you defined in the function.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDEX(A1:C17,MATCH(UNIQUE(B1:B17),B1:B17,0),SEQUENCE(,3))
```

- The `MATCH` function returns an array of the first matching row number for each unique element in the array.
- The `columns` argument for the `SEQUENCE` function represents the number of columns in the array. This could be computed if that value is unknown or may vary.

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you very much!